# JAX-RS SSE connection closing abruptly

Tags: java, servlets, jax-rs, server-sent-events

I'm trying to create a SSE using JAX-RS with the following code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.sse.OutboundSseEvent;
import javax.ws.rs.sse.Sse;
import javax.ws.rs.sse.SseEventSink;

@Path("events")
public class EventsHandler {

    
    Executor executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public void sendEvents(@Context SseEventSink sseEventSink, @Context Sse sse) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        IntStream rndStream = IntStream.generate(() -> rnd.nextInt(90));
        List<Integer> lottery = rndStream.limit(5).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            lottery.forEach(value -> {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                    System.out.println("Sending the following value: " + value);
                    final OutboundSseEvent outboundSseEvent = sse.newEventBuilder().name("lottery")
                            .data(Integer.class, value).build();
                    sseEventSink.send(outboundSseEvent);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            sseEventSink.close();
        });
    }
}
```

However, every attempt to run it on my Wildfly Server throws the message `Failed to set servlet request into asynchronous mode, server sent events may not work` with no further details.

I tried to change the asyncSupport in the servlet config to true, but it had no effect.

**EDIT 05/15/2023** 
The problem was the others filters used in the web.xml, all involved filters on the servlet must enable the async support.

Comment: What version of Wildfly are you using?

Comment: I'm using Wildfly 21